# Working with Unicode file path

Tags: java, windows, file-io, unicode

In my copy of Windows, the path separator is not a backslash but a Korean Won currency sign, which is character U20A9 in Unicode.

However, when my program searches for this character in a string representing a file path, it doesn't find it, even though it appears as expected when the path is printed.

My program is registered with Explorer to appear in the right-click menu for files, so it receives the file path from Explorer as a command-line argument.

What is going on here?  How can I locate the path separators in the command-line argument?

Comment: See my answer. If you use the right codepoint, it will display as Won, but it is actually the path separator. What is your code, and what exception do you get when you try and open the file?

Comment: After reading your explanation, I went looking for a different point of failure, and found that the check File.exists() always returned false and caused the problem. This is true for any file, regardless of the file's access permission, so I don't think this is a file permission problem, although I haven't tried accessing the file yet. Will update after trying.

Comment: Yep, my code can't get to the file. FileNotFoundException
The file returns false for: exists, canRead, canExecute, canWrite

Comment: @user2444520: Strictly speaking, since you've determined that your problem was unrelated to the question, it should probably be closed as "caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced" but I'd like to save Andy's excellent answer.  If you don't object, I'd like to rewrite it accordingly?

Comment: No objection here. Hack away

Comment: Finally got around to it!  Hope this meets your approval, but if there's anything about it you don't like, feel free to change it or simply revert it to your original version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a Japanese or Korean version of Windows? In that case the path symbol should still be <kbd>U+005C</kbd> which is *displayed* as (but not actually the same codepoint as) the local currency character (e.g. <kbd>₩</kbd> and <kbd>¥</kbd>) instead of <kbd>\</kbd>. If you try searching for <kbd>U+005C</kbd> instead of <kbd>U+20A9</kbd>, does that work?

But, I am confused about this bit of your question:

> Java can't open the file as a File object because the file separator in my copy of Windows is not a backslash, it is a Korean Won currency sign (U20A9).

It should still work, as long as you are not typing in test paths yourself, and using the "wrong" version of the currency character (and as long as there are no other problems with the file). It might help if we could see your code.

#### Why the different displays for the same codepoint/character?

The reason is the code pages used for display. Kaplan used to have a blog post about this on MSDN, but it's disappeared. It basically said "*Japanese code page 932: 0x005C is the YEN SIGN. Korean code page 949: 0x005C is the WON SIGN.*"

See [MSDN:Security Considerations: International Features (Security Considerations for Character Sets in File Names)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374047%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#SC_char_sets_in_file_names).

> Windows code page and OEM character sets used on Japanese-language systems contain the Yen symbol (¥) instead of a backslash (\). ... When mapping Unicode to a Japanese-language code page, conversion functions map both backslash (U+005C) and the normal Unicode Yen symbol (U+00A5) to this same character.

As per that reference above note that if you try and use the actual Won and Yen characters (<kbd>U+00A5</kbd> and <kbd>U+20A9</kbd>) as path separators you can't without mapping/having them mapped to <kbd>U+005C</kbd>.

*Relevant Trivia*

I cannot recall where I read this, but it helps to understand why this all happens, and why <kbd>/</kbd> works in a file path.

Apparently the reason windows uses <kbd>\</kbd> instead of *nix's <kbd>/</kbd> is because (when DOS was born) someone who made a lot of DOS programs in MS/IBM used <kbd>/</kbd> as the "switch" character for DOS programs? This was a decision that <strike>possibly</strike> came from <strike>even before DOS</strike> CP/M, through QDOS, to MSDOS. DOS didn't support directories so the clash with *nix didn't matter. By the time DOS 2.0 came along with files and file paths they wanted a *nix style file path naming system but couldn't use the "DOS switch" <kbd>/</kbd> so they used <kbd>\</kbd> instead.

BUT - they coded DOS to **accept both <kbd>\</kbd> and /** as they really would have preferred to use the *nix style. (They also added a OS mechanism to change the switch character, which I can't remember, but the windows world never fully "switched" over to the *nix style of paths and switches).

**EDIT**

Found it: [Shebang line on Windows](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2013-February/641597.html):

> Dave Angel davea at davea.name
>
> Tue Feb 26 03:23:58 CET 2013
>
> Actually the reason MSDOS used backslash was because it had already used 
>   the forward slash for a switch-character.  Then for version 2, with hard 
>   disks being supported for the first time, they used the backslash 
>   instead.  At the time I talked them into supporting a "switchchar" call 
>   to change to using the dash for switch character, and slash for 
>   subdirectories.

Comment: Re Trivia - you probably read this [here](http://superuser.com/questions/176388/why-does-windows-use-backslashes-for-paths-and-unix-forward-slashes) and/or in the blog post it references.

Comment: I heard a rumour there was life before SO ;) I think it was on Michael Kaplan's blog, sometime around when I was asking him about Welsh language localisation. All his posts seem to have disappeared now, annoyingly. That's a good superuser post though, at least the knowledge isn't lost forever!

Comment: @HarryJohnston And you're right, it was probably also on Osterman's ["Why is the DOS path character "\"?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2005/06/24/432386.aspx) - thanks for helping me find it again!

Comment: Just as a heads-up, I've rewritten the question (with the OPs approval) to better reflect the on-topic aspect and avoid the confusion caused by the unrelated issue.  You may (or may not) wish to edit your answer accordingly.

Comment: It should also perhaps be pointed out that while DOS fully supported both backslash and forward slash, *Windows* support for the forward slash is a little half-hearted.  The kernel doesn't support it at all.  Most Win32 functions will convert forward slashes to backslashes under most circumstances, but I don't think the support is entirely comprehensive.  The command line only accepts it sometimes. :-)

Answer (score 0):

While I don't have a Korean or Japanese version of Windows, I believe you should call `System.getProperty("file.separator")` to get the proper file-separator character:

```
// fps means file-path-separator
static final String fps = System.getProperty("file.separator")
```

This is not always the one used by the in a terminal or command prompt, but it should work. On the Macintosh before OSX, the Mac used a colon for the file separator, but this got translated to a slash when reading files through Java. This was also the character returned by the file.separator system property.